# Redirect all DNS request with ASA5505 to one specific DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, cisco-asa

I want to make it so if a user tries to use a different DNS server the request will be redirected to the one they should be using.

Looks like this might work:

```
ip access-list extended transparent_dns
permit udp any any eq 53

route-map redirect_dns permit 10
match ip address transparent_dns
set ip next-hop ip.of.your.server
route-map redirect_dns permit 20

interface fax/x
ip address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
ip policy route-map redirect_dns
```

I'm assuming this will work on the ASA. Any ideas on another way to do this or if this will even work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASA does not support policy based routing. It does however support policy NAT which may allow you to NAT all of your DNS queries to a single DNS server. Another option is to run a WCCP redirect but this requires support from your OS and possibly your DNS server.

Comment: I see how WCCP can redirect HTTP and HTTPS traffic but I don't see how to set up the DNS side of it, any info on that? Same goes for the policy based NAT. I'll have to look around for some info. Thanks for the ideas.